Duplicate CSV row, changing a cell value
TL:DR
For every permission Space in my CSV (below) that grants permission to the RBAC group ABC, I need to duplicate the row and grant the same permission to RBAC group XYZ.
The long version:
I have a CSV of permission values for each Space that's thousands of lines long. I need to
Find each unique Space-name row containing permission group ID 'ABC' for a given Space
Check for Space rows that do not also contain a permission row for group ID 'XYZ'
Duplicate that row and change grpID to 'ABC' so that for each row with an XYZ permission, there's now an ABC permission and an XYZ permission for each Space
In the example below, the AcmeCorp Space has the correct permission groups, both ABC and XYZ. BetaCorp would meet the requirements of 1 and 2 above. CharlieCorp lacks the ABC permission group, so would get passed over. I need a way to duplicate the row containing BetaCorp,global,ABC, changing ABC to XYZ so that there are now one row for each permission group.
I've tried to record keystrokes and save it as a script, but it's only copying the value of the cell id (e.g. ("A58")) instead of finding a cell with a value of 'XYZ'.
EDIT: Office M365 (Version 16.87 (24061913)
EDIT: User groups are granted access to a Space (see below). We're moving away from random permission group names to something more specific and easily repeatable and identifiable. This is intended to be as nonspecific as possible. Consider this to be a CSV exported from anything that has RBAC users and groups.
CSV Screenshot

You can solve this problem using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365 (Windows or Mac)
To use Power Query

Select some cell in your Data Table

Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range

Instead of above, you can use =>from Text/CSV and read the CSV file directly.


When the PQ Editor opens: Home => Advanced Editor

Depending on your data source, paste the appropriate lines from the code below into the editor, replacing what is there.

Read the comments and explore the Applied Steps to understand the algorithm


let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Space", type text}, {"Space Name", type text}, {"Space Type", type text}, {"Id", type text}}),

//or paste the code below here after the first few lines in your generated code.

//Group by Space Name
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Space Name"}, {

    //Check if bothe or neither "ABC","XYZ" then no change
    // else if "ABC" present then duplicate row except change "ABC" to "XYZ"
        {"add ABC", (t)=> if List.ContainsAll(t[Id],{"ABC","XYZ"}) 
                then t
            else if List.Contains(t[Id], "ABC")
                then t & Table.ReplaceValue(Table.SelectRows(t, each [Id]="ABC"),"ABC","XYZ",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Id"})
                else t,
             type table [Space=nullable text, Space Name=nullable text, Space Type=nullable text, Id=nullable text]}}),

//Remove unneeded column and epand the Grouped table
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Space Name"}),
    #"Expanded add ABC" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "add ABC",{"Space", "Space Name", "Space Type", "Id"})
in
    #"Expanded add ABC"


